# Schengen visa for Finland

Tags: visas, schengen

I am travelling to Helsinki for a conference for 4 days, I will apply to the Finnish embassy for a Schengen visa. If I want to travel to Tallinn, Estonia for a couple of days, do I have to apply for a separate visa or is my Schengen visa obtained for Finland valid?

Answer (score 3):

Since both Finland and Estonia are full members of the [Schengen agreement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schengen_Agreement), your Finnish visa is valid in Estonia - that's exactly the point of a Schengen visa.